# How to add custom applications/scripts in startup applications in 14.10?

Tags: gnome, scripts, 14.10, startup, startup-applications

I'm trying to run a script automatically on bootup but am unable to do so because

- my Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 doesn't have a Startup Applications manager
- I can't add any custom scripts through running Tweak tool (with sudo priveledges) since it only allows to add existing applications
- I'm unable to install Startup applications because every time I trying to install gnome-session-properties, it tells me to install gnome-session-bin, which is already currently installed and at the newest level of update.

Can someone please help me find an alternative or a fix for 14.10?

Comment: If you're using Gnome Ubuntu, you should already have gnome-session-properties in your system, what happens when you try running gnome-session-properties? Try reinstalling gnome-session-bin.

Comment: gnome-session-properties is not there for his system.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Arronax](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/) to create a starter for your script and save it into `$HOME/.config/autostart/` (that's "User Autostart Folder" in the "Standard Folders" list in the lower left of the "Save File" dialog)

Answer (score 0):

The **startup applications GUI** can be made to re-appear by removing a gnome3 ppa:
  $ sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

This hasn't had any bad effects on my 14.10 system, and the startup application re-appeared.

You can also figure out the scripts in ~/.config/autostart/, and in /etc/init.d/, and use those to manage your startup programs.

There is also a program **Arronax** at http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/, but I have no experience with this software.

Comment: Installing a PPA for this is not  good. PPAs risk the integrity of the system.